# Can we produce haptics and record from microphone the haptic sound at the same time on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, vibration

I am trying to make a vibration test which produces vibration for 3 sec and tries to record the vibration, the goal is to analyze frequency of vibration so that we can check if vibration is working on my iphone and if the vibration or haptic motor isn't faulty.

I have tried calling both the functions asynchronously and the print statement to trace the function work completely fine, however the vibration doesnt perform when recording and vibration are performed simultaneously

Below is the code implementation:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Accelerate
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {
    
    var vibrationTimer: Timer?
    var endTime: Date?
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?
  
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
   }
    
    @IBAction func testButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
     
        playVibrationForDuration(seconds: 3)
    }
    //play vibration
    
    func playVibrationForDuration(seconds: TimeInterval) {
           // Set the end time for vibration
           endTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(seconds)
           
           // Start playing vibration and record it simultaneously using Dispatch queue for asyncjronous calls
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    // Start vibration
                 self.startVibration()
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    // Start recording
                    self.startRecording()
                }
           
       }
       
       func startVibration() {
           print("Vibration starts")
           // Schedule timer to play vibration repeatedly
           vibrationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(playVibration), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
       }
       
       @objc func playVibration() {
           guard let endTime = endTime, Date() < endTime else {
               // Stop the vibration when the end time is reached
               stopVibration()
               
               return
           }
           // Play system sound for vibration
           AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1352)
       }
       
       func stopVibration() {
           // Invalidate timer to stop vibration
           vibrationTimer?.invalidate()
           print("Vibration stops")
           
       }
    
    //record the vibrations produced
    
    
    func startRecording() {
        print("Recording started")
        let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("recording.m4a")
        
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]
        
        do {
            audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            audioRecorder?.delegate = self
            audioRecorder?.record()
        } catch {
            print("Error recording audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        // analyzeRecordedVibration(audioURL: audioFilename)
    }
    
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
```

I haven't incuded the code for analysis part.